# Toast before async task with get() method not shown until async task is finished

Tags: asynchronous, get, toast

I have an async task which gets some info and pass it back to the main thread. So, I'm using the get() method. I know you cannot update the UI once you have such an async task running (it is more a sync task). All I want is giving a previous message with a simple Toast before I call the async task. More or less as:

Toast with the message

asynctask.execute(...).get()

But the Toast message is always shown only when the async task finishes.

Is there a way for showing a message before a call to an async task with get method?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post some code. It's hard to help you without that.